# Return empty string for no match on DateTime

Tags: t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

Table [docSVdate]
PK sID, fielID
value DateTime not null

If there is no row for a given PK (sID, fieldID) I need to return an empty string
This is the best I could come up with
Does anyone have something more efficient?

```
  select isnull(convert(varchar,[docSVdate].[value]), '')
    from [docSVsys] as [pholder] with (nolock) 
    left join [docSVdate] 
      on [docSVdate].[sID] = [pholder].[sID]
     and [docSVdate].[fieldID] = 117
   where [pholder].[sID] = 6485
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the `datetime` to a `varchar` in SQL, you are introducing the language and culture settings of your SQL Server into the date string.  You might also be losing precision, depending on exactly what format is being used.  And there's potential for error if the application code parses the string differently than SQL produced it.

So the simple answer is - don't do this.  Just return it as a `datetime`.  Let the calling application use it directly without converting to a string.  Check for null if necessary in the calling application.

If you *really* want to do this, then there are many techniques that might work, including the join you showed, and the variable the Luis showed in his answer.  Here is another technique, which uses a nested query.  Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT ISNULL(
    (select convert(varchar, [value])
     from [docSVDate]
     where [sID] = 6485 and [fieldID] = 117
    ), '') as [value]
```

Please be aware that conversion from `datetime` to `varchar` involves formatting, whether you like it or not.  If you don't specify anything, you get the defaults for whatever system you are running on.  For me, running on a database with US English settings, my default format looks like `"Jul 21 2013  4:41PM"`  But if I had different language settings, I might get a completely different result.  You should probably pass a format specifier to indicate what format you are looking for.  Please reference the [Date and Time Styles remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in the MSDN reference for cast/convert.

Comment: Not at all an answer to the stated question.

Comment: It may not be the answer you're looking for, but it does raise the specter of a question that should be considered: what do you do with the rows that DO match?  Do you care if the value comes back as a string, or do you need to work with a datetime?

Comment: @Blam - please provide an example of the desired format of the date/time string you're looking for.

Comment: @MattJohnson Why, the question is not about formatting.  The sample code provided produces acceptable format.  The stated question is "Does anyone have something more efficient?"

Comment: @StuartAinsworth Really?  Think about it.  Empty string is not a valid DataTime so clearly it cannot be returning a DateTime.  I need exactly what I am asking for.  I need to return an empty string for no match.

Comment: @Blam - I am just trying to help, no need to get an attitude.  I will update my answer momentarily, but since you are asking for efficiency improvements, then technically your question belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) rather than on StackOverflow...

Comment: Thanks.  But your original answer was attitude.  Rather than address the stated question you dismissed it as "don't do this".   Now that you accepted the question as stated I like your answer.  Let me test the performance.

Answer (score 2):

**if it's just one row...**

INNER JOIN? 
I'm not sure what the execution plan will show

```
  DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(50)
  SET @Value = ''

  SELECT @Value  = convert(varchar,[docSVdate].[value])
    FROM [docSVsys] as [pholder] with (nolock) 
    INNER JOIN [docSVdate] 
      ON [docSVdate].[sID] = [pholder].[sID]
         AND [docSVdate].[fieldID] = 117
   WHERE [pholder].[sID] = 6485

  SELECT @Value as Value
```

Does not need a join at all.
At most one row as the where is the PK,

```
DECLARE @Value VARCHAR(50)
  SET @Value = ''

  SELECT @Value  = convert(varchar,[docSVdate].[value])
    FROM [docSVdate]         
   WHERE [docSVdate].[sID] = 6485
     AND [docSVdate].[fieldID] = 117

  SELECT @Value as Value
```

Comment: Don't need a join at all.  I am using this to build up a larger query so the format does not fit but it is slick.

Comment: If you don't need the JOIN for sure this really could be the fastest.